# Webkit command-line interface

Tags: command-line, webkit, inspector

Is there a way to retrieve information from a WebKit build using command-line? I'm particularly interested in retrieving information from the "Inspector Panel" such as the Network panel with resource timing and size info.

The idea is to use the information in a real-time web analysis, speed test project like http://www.webpagetest.org/